# Asymptotic behaviour of implicit functions

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

Suppose we have an implicit equation $F\left(x,y\right)=0$ which we know defines $y = y(x)$ as a function of $x$. Are there sufficient or necessary conditions under which we can obtain information about the asymptotic behaviour of $y(x)$? Particularly, what is the limit $\lim _{x\to +\infty }y\left(x\right)$ (if it even exists)? Or if we constrain ourselves to the domain $x,y>0$ then what is $\lim _{x\to 0^+ }y\left(x\right)?$

Comment: If you give me an example to study I'll be more clear.

Comment: The implicit equation is $F\left(a,t\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int _0^p\:\sqrt{1+\left(arx^{r-1}\right)^2}dx$, where $p=\left(\frac{t+ak^r}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}$ and $a,t,k,r > 0$, $k,r$ constant. I already proved that if you fix $t = t_0$ then $F(a,t_0)$ is increasing and that $F(a,t_0)$ only has one root when solving for $a$. So $a = a(t)$ and I am interested in its limit as $t \to \infty$ and $t \to 0+$. You gave me a direction of thought. @Vajra

Comment: My question is still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say anything in general. The implicit function theorem only guarantees that for every $(x_0, y_0)$ such that $F(x_0, y_0) = 0$ and $\partial_yF(x_0, y_0)\neq 0$, there is a (possibly small) neighborhood of $x_0$ where $y$ is defined as an implicit function of $x$. That neighborhood could be a very small interval, so $y(x)$ may not be defined for arbitrarily large values of $x$.

Simple example: $F(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 -1$ is the circle. There, $x$ can only go from $-1$ to $1$. You can't take the limit when $x\rightarrow \infty$. So first, you should assume that the $x$ coordinate is unbounded in the set $F(x,y) = 0$. But that may not be enough because the implicit function theorem is still local, and only gives local information (i.e., near the point $x_0$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't answer my question. I know the implicit function theorem only gives us local information about the implicit function, but I am talking about case where it is known (not necessarily using the implicit function theorem) that for all $x_0$ the equation $F(x_0,y) = 0$ has only one solution $y = y_0$.  Under this assumption, are there any necessary, or even better, sufficient conditions which tell us whether the limit converges? If so, is there a way/an algorithm to calculate it?

Comment: Well, when $x$ varies and gets arbitrarily large $y(x) $ takes values in order to make the expression $F(x, y(x)) $ constantly equal to zero. That suggests looking at the expression of $F$ and asking, "is there a value for $y$ that makes the expression $F(\infty, y) $ take a finite value (in fact, that makes it equal to zero) ?" Maybe that's all there is to it, put $x=\infty$ in $F$ and find a value of $y$ (which will Be the limit) that makes the expression zero. For example, in $F(x, y) = xy-1$, you can tell that the limit should be zero (because that way $\infty\cdot 0$ could be $1$).

Comment: The limit existing just means that the curve has an horizontal asymptote. Usually, there are no additional conditions or algorithms for calculating asymptotes. I think of them as derivatives: the definition is enough, and you go check each case looking for them.

Comment: Another idea: if the limit existed, the tangent line should approach an horizontal line ($y'(x) $ should go to zero). Deriving equation $F(x, y(x)) =0$ one gets $\partial_x F + \partial_y F y'(x) =0$, so $y'(x) = - \partial_x F/\partial_y F$, and we get the necessart condition: $\partial_x F$ must go to zero when $x$ goes to infinity (or maybe $\partial_y F$ goes to infinity).

Comment: The problem is that, generally speaking, $\partial _x F$ and $\partial _y F$ contains $y(x)$ in their expression. So To calculate the limit you will generally need to calculate the limits of $y(x)$, which is just circular.

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying about an algorithm for calculating asymptotes. There isn't one for a general function $f(x)$ (just methods that rise when the defenition is given) so I understand why I am not getting a definitive answer. This is however something that might be worth to look at at a later date. If no one answers soon, I will award you the bounty :)

Comment: No bounty? You lied :(

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't let me anymore I didn't know there is a time limit